# add additional header to symfony mailer message

Tags: php, symfony

I don't use the Symfony Framework. When I add my header like

```
$mail = (new Email())
    ->from(new Address('info@example.com', 'Name'))
    ->to($recipient)
    ->subject($subject)
    ->html($body)
    ->getHeaders()
        ->addTextHeader('X-Auto-Response-Suppress', 'OOF, DR, RN, NRN, AutoReply');
```

then a `$mailer->send($mail);` doesn't work anymore:-(

How do I send mail?

Comment: I forgot the message is : Expected type 'Symfony\Component\Mime\RawMessage'. Found 'Symfony\Component\Mime\Header\Headers'

Comment: Updating php to what your symphony library requires may solve your probelm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`getHeaders` function returns the Headers, so in your `$mail`, you dont have an email but Headers

```php
            $mail = (new Email())
                ->from(new Address('info@example.com', 'Name'))
                ->to($recipient)
                ->subject($subject)
                ->html($body);
            $mail->getHeaders()->addTextHeader('X-Auto-Response-Suppress', 'OOF, DR, RN, NRN, AutoReply');
```